# How to check for null values?

Tags: c#, .net, subsonic

I have an integer column that may have a number or nothing assigned to it (i.e. null in the database). How can I check if it is null or not?

I have tried

```
if(data.ColumnName == null)
{
    ...
}
```

This doesn't work either (as SubSonic does not use nullable types (when applicable) for ActiveRecord)

```
if(data.ColumnName.HasValue)
{
    ...
}
```

If the value stored in the database is 0, then this wouldn't help:

```
if(data.ColumnName == 0 /* or 0x000? */)
{
    ...
}
```

The same problem could also occur with DateTime fields as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it. SubSonic has a method for getting the value as an object to allow a null check:

```
if(data.GetColumnValue("Column Name") == null)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

If (data == System.DBNull)

Comment: Except that wouldn't compile. You mean either { data == System.DBNull.Value } or { data is System.DBNull }.

Comment: Yeah, i have to admit, i wrote that fast and didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

if your **data** variable is a strongly typed datarow, this might help :

```
if(data.IsNull("ColumnName")) { ... }
```

Comment: data is a SubSonic ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

DBNull is the value of a null column.

DBNull is a value type. Value types cannot be null.

Assuming a SqlDataReader ... checking for null is :

if (reader["colname") == DBNull.Value)

Answer (score 0):

When querying the database handle the null there, makes your life a lot easier in the code

SQL example

```
SELECT isNull(columnName, 0) FROM TABLENAME...
```

or

```
Select isNUll(columnName, 'N/A') FROM TABLENAME ...
```